# How to resolve 500 - Internal server error?

Tags: database, installation

I could not able to figure how to resolve this error i have tried searching on google.

> Server Error
>
> 500 - Internal server error.
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I have succesfully uploaded my site in a folder on godaddy's server and also import database.but when i am getting this error on browser, also checked my server log and also uncomment "rewritebase /" in .htaccess file

Please suggest how to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check your server logs?

Comment: Sorry but it's impossible to help you with this without more information. Please inspect your server logs (your  hosting provider can tell you where these are if you're not sure) and update the question when you have specific error messages. 9 times out of 10 with these things the problem is with restrictions placed on the .htaccess file by the hosting provider. Quite often `<IfModule>` and others aren't supported, which Drupal's .htaccess uses.

Comment: Check you error logs.. That might give you an idea...

Answer (score 1):

Could be any number of things.

Check the server error log or stick:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in your settings.php file (remove once in production environment) to force PHP to show errors.

Comment: I have put these code in setting.php and again uploaded, but still showing the same error

Comment: Check the server error logs then

Comment: i have checked the server log